# How can I properly install and invoke 'r2snow' radare2 decompiler?

Tags: bash, decompiler, radare2

I have spent the past several hours attempting to install a decompiler with no success. Since I've recently been using [radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) as a disassembler, I figured using the associated decompiler package would work well. After finding out that [radeco](https://github.com/radareorg/radeco) and [radeco-lib](https://github.com/radareorg/radeco-lib/) aren't currently stable enough to build, I used their package manager [r2pm](https://github.com/radare/radare2-pm) to finally install the [r2snow](https://github.com/radare/radare2-extras/tree/master/r2snowman) BASH script in `~/.local/share/radare2/prefix/bin`.

But now I cannot figure out how to run it to decompile a binary! The error message I receive is: `"Usage: r2 -i '.!r2snow'"`. I know that `r2` is shorthand for `radare2`, and the `-i` flag is to pass a script file to run, but I've tried passing it the r2snow BASH script in multiple ways with no success.

Does anyone with experience using this particular decompiler know how to properly invoke it? Normally I could figure this out myself, but the lack of proper documentation has proved too difficult.

I kid you not, every time you invoke the program improperly, it taunts you. Most recently: `"Usage: r2 -i '.!r2snow'" -- This should be documented, since it's not that obvious.` Maybe I should try a different decompiler altogether. Are there any free decompilers out there which are easier to set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install radare2 plugins you should start with:

```
$ r2pm init
$ r2pm update
```

Then install your desired plugin using `r2pm`:

```
$ r2pm -i r2snow
```

You might get this error:

> ERROR: Build failed. You probably need 'brew install cartr/qt4/qt' and
>   'brew install boost' or 'sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libqt4-dev'

So simply install the missing libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libqt4-dev'
```

Then, you can call r2snow from wihtin r2 shell via `!r2snow` or from outside like `r2 -i '.!r2snow' /bin/ls`

---

Instead of r2snow, I'd suggest using `r2dec` or `r2retdec`.

To install `r2dec`:

```
$ r2pm -i r2dec
```

And then simply use `pdd`:

```
$ r2 -A my_file
...
[0x00000540]> s main
[0x000006a4]> pdd
int32_t main () {
    /* arg1 */
    *(local_14h) = edi;
    /* arg2 */
    *(local_20h) = rsi;
    esi = 7;
    edi = 0x61;
    print_it (*(local_20h), *(local_14h));
    esi = 0x11;
    edi = 0x6b;
    print_it (edi, esi);
    *(local_4h) = 5;
    edx = *(local_4h);
    eax = edx;
    eax += eax;
    eax += edx;
    *(local_4h) = eax;
    eax = *(local_4h);
    edi = eax;
    dumb_function (edi);
    esi = 9;
    edi = 0x62;
    print_it (edi, esi);
    eax = 0;
    return eax;
}
```

To install `r2retdec`:

```
$ r2pm -i r2retdec
```

Make sure to have `npm` installed and follow the instructions in the [repository](https://github.com/securisec/r2retdec). 
After you installed it, use `$dec` from within r2 shell.

Comment: Thanks, but after installing exactly as mentioned, whenever I try `r2 -i '.!r2snow' /bin/ls`, I get `Script '.!r2snow' not found.`. I'll try `r2dec` now.

Comment: Great, `r2dec` works for me! Is there any option to decompile an entire binary, instead of a specific function?

Comment: Nope, it is not design for such purpose. Anyway, r2dec is a pseudo decompiler, try making r2retdec work for the best decompilation experience