# How to fix "r_cons.h/r_types.h:no such file or directory" while installing r2dec

Tags: c, radare2

I'm trying to install r2dec plugin for radare2. The Build fails because there are some files missing.

first I did run following commands

> $r2pm init

then

> $r2pm init

then i tried to install it with :

> $r2pm -i r2dec

When the build failed I installed npm because a comment on this answer suggested it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51466052/10854709

> $sudo apt install nodejs

Expected output would be a successful build.

the actual output is the following:

Install Done For r2dec
make: Entering directory '/home/me/.local/share/radare2/r2pm/git/r2dec-js/p'
cc -I/home/me/.local/share/radare2/prefix/include -g -O3 -I/usr/include/libr -I./duktape -L/home/me/.local/share/radare2/prefix/lib -lr_core -lr_config -lr_debug -lr_bin -lr_anal -lr_bp -lr_egg -lr_asm -lr_lang -lr_parse -lr_flag -lr_cons -lr_reg -lr_search -lr_syscall -lr_fs -lr_io -lr_socket -lr_magic -lr_crypto -lr_hash -lr_util -ldl -lm -std=c99 -shared -fPIC duktape/duktape.c duktape/duk_console.c core_pdd.c -o core_pdd.so

duktape/duk_console.c:13:20: fatal error: r_cons.h: No such file or directory

[..]
core_pdd.c:8:21: fatal error: r_types.h: No such file or directory

[..]

compilation terminated.
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/me/.local/share/radare2/r2pm/git/r2dec-js/p'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `sudo apt install pkg-config`

Answer (score 1):

libzip is one of the requirements to install r2dec. For some reason, I cannot find the webpage that explained the dependency, but I remember seeing it. libzip was already installed, but the "dev" package, which contains the headers for the library, wasn't. Installing libzip-dev seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: How did installing lib zip solve the issue. In general, while solving an issue is very much welcomed, please try to provide some context about how the answer solved the problem .

Comment: Thanks, camba1. I added more details to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you install radare2 using a package manager you may not have the header files for radare2 itself (and if you're using the github repo I guess the r2pm installer isn't pointing to it or something?.

You only need to install radare2-devel....or whatever package it is for your system then r2dec will build okay. The relevant headers are part of that package.

For me on Fedora,

```
dnf install radare2-devel
```